# Kendo UI Multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui

I've been using the new Kendo UI Multiselect widget with server-side filtering, but I'm having trouble getting it to only make the ajax call after a minimum number of characters have been entered. I've set the autoBind and minLength options to false and 3 respectively. However it sends an ajax request to get the select options as soon as I put my cursor into the text field. It does wait until 3 characters (or more) are entered before sending another ajax request and refreshing the options list. But how do I make it wait until 3 characters have been entered before the first ajax request is sent? Here is how I've configured the the multiSelect:

```
  $('#delegates').kendoMultiSelect(
        {
            autoBind: false,
            minLength: 3,
            placeholder: 'Select delegates...',
            dataTextField: 'name',
            dataValueField: 'personid',
            filter: 'contains',
            delay: 200,
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/my/remote/url',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

I've looked at the [overview](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/multiselect/overview) and [API docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect) for the MultiSelect widgets on the KendoUI site and it doesn't even appear that there's a way to do what I'm talking about (I initially thought the autoBind: false and minLength: 3 would be my answer, but turns out it's not). So I"m posting in the hopes that maybe I've missed something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't prevent the inital bug, but can't you just ignore on your server-method if the posted value is an empty string, and return nothing?

Comment: @Shion -- yep, I thought about that and it does make sense. It seems like a workaround, though, so I wanted to make sure there wasn't a built-in way to make it wait for the ajax call. If not I'll probably do exactly as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the workaround.

If I inspect the KendoUI demos here: [Server Filtering Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/serverfiltering.html) with FireBug, an initial call is made as soon as the page has loaded.
I think that is by design, and is as expected in the current version of the widget.

Since this is a new widget, try contacting the Kendo-Team. With a bit of luck, in the next release (or some beta in between) there will be an option for this.

Comment: Hi, so is there a new version of Kendo that addresses this issue?

Comment: I don't know. Try fiddling with their demos and inspect them with firebug/web inspector. Additionally make a minimal demo which tests this behaviour. If you get any information, let us know by commenting here and I'll update my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
                        placeholder: "Select products...",
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataValueField: "id",
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataSource: {
                            transport:{
                                read:{
                                    url:'products/api/get',
                                    serverPaging:true,
                                    pageSize:20,
                                    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    type:'GET',
                                    dataType:'json'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```